# How does the Wizarding World print newspapers and books?

Tags: harry-potter

I know that this kind of question seems to stupid, but in the wizarding world, there is no such thing as 'computers' or 'printers'.

Honestly, after reading every books of Harry Potter, there is no interesting fact of how they publish newspapers same with the books. Of course, newspapers won't come to readers as handwritten, it'll be unpleasant. And same with the books?

How do they manage those kind of things, unless they use Muggle stuff?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_printing

Comment: Heh... yes, in real life, the printing press was first invented in 1440. Google "Gutenberg Printing Press"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wizards use magically-operated printing presses.

> *Luna was not there: the thing that was making such a racket was a
> wooden object covered in magically turning cogs and wheels. It looked
> like the bizarre offspring of a workbench and a set of old shelves,
> but after a moment Harry deduced that it was an old-fashioned printing
> press due to the fact that it was churning out Quibblers.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter Twenty: Xenophilius Lovegood</sup></sub>

It's not entirely clear from the text if they're using **offset printing** (the kind that prints from a [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_printing)) or **movable type** (the kind where you use [letter blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movable_type)) but it seems likely that it's the former given the presence of rollers. In the film you can clearly see that it's a roller-printer.

On top of that, pictures in muggle newspapers don't [*typically*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8u3OfKG3tI) move so there's probably something magical in the ink used.

[image]

---

The Ministry uses magic to assemble pamphlets from what appear to be pre-printed sheets of paper

> *Harry paused to watch them, for the effect was quite mesmerising. They
> were all waving and twiddling their wands in unison, and squares of
> coloured paper were flying in every direction like little pink kites.
> After a few seconds, Harry realised that there was a rhythm to the
> proceedings, that the papers all formed the same pattern, and after a
> few more seconds he realised that what he was watching was the
> creation of pamphlets, that the paper squares were pages, which when
> assembled, folded and magicked into place, fell into neat stacks
> beside each witch or wizard.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter Thirteen: The Muggle-Born Registration Commission</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer by addressing the pamphlet-producers outside Umbridge’s office, in the chapter _The Muggle-born Registration Commission_, too?

Comment: BTW, the chapter you are quoting from is titled _Xenophilius Lovegood_ in my edition (Bloomsbury, first edition, 2007; hardcover). What edition do you have?

Comment: @chirlu - It's the title for the article on pottermore that contains the quote; https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/a-visit-to-the-lovegoods